# How does people do blood moon rising solo in overwatch?

Tags: overwatch

I got some video

However, I thought that's impossible. If you play you always have 4 people at once. So how can some people play solo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to that Youtuber's [comment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=znFKDjBv-K4&lc=UgwXNVG96DxI-hMhk114AaABAg.96Ac7e-PWb196HlSoelYx4) on another video:

> I have extra accounts I use to abandon the match once it starts so I can solo

So essentially he uses his four Overwatch accounts to start the game, and then leaves with the other three. The game doesn't try to backfill these events, so it's then possible to complete the mission solo. Having three friends who own the game help with this would also work of course.